# How do I make a background "square" responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I'm new to css, and I added this orange square to the background of this image, but when I make the screen width smaller the shape changes. How do I make it stay the same as the screen size shrinks?

[This is what the square looks like at full screen size and what I want it to keep looking at when the screen shrinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiw5h.jpg)

[This is what the orange square currently does when the screen width shrinks. I have been trying to get it to look like the image about instead, but haven't figured it out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4hfH.png)

Here's how I added the orange square to the images:

```
.home .posts :nth-child(2n-1) .img::after{
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,145,77,255);
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.home .post .img{
    flex:1;
    position: relative;

}
```

The jsx looks like this

```
const posts =[
    {
      id:1,
      title: "Beyond me by Yadah",
      desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur vitae ad vel quidem saepe?",
      img:"https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273f476b41122fd3382c573e3dc"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title: "Only Yeshua by Caleb David",
      desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur vitae ad vel quidem saepe?",
      img:"https://i0.wp.com/revelationmusik.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/caleb-new-artwork1.jpg"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      title: "Eze Ebube by Neon Adejo",
      desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur vitae ad vel quidem saepe?",
      img:"https://i0.wp.com/gospelhotspot.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Eze-Ebube-Neon-Adejo.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1"
    }
    
  ]

return (
    <div className='home'>
    <div className='posts'>
      {posts.map(post=>(
        <div className='post' key={post.id}>
          <div className='img'>
            <Link className="link-img " to={`/post/${post.id}`}><img src={post.img} alt={post.title} /></Link>
          </div>

          <div className='content'>
            <Link className="link" to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            </Link>
            <p>{post.desc}</p>
            <button>Read More</button>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Please please please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong

I've tried writing media queries for when the screen width is shrunken, but it had no effect.

Comment: can you post your html as well

Comment: You have .post in one setting and .posts in the other. Is this correct? We need your HTML including the class attributes.

Comment: This can be easily done using just `aspect-ratio: 1`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: I tried adding aspect-ratio: 1, but it has no effect.